# Not able to receive value in response in flutter to cashfree API

Tags: flutter, api, dart, cashfree

I'm trying to receive response `order_token` from test API `https://sandbox.cashfree.com/pg/orders` which is used to create session of a payment gateway. Here is the code.

```
  CFEnvironment environment = CFEnvironment.SANDBOX;

  Future<dynamic> createOrder() async {
    var response = await http.post(
      Uri.https('https://sandbox.cashfree.com/pg/orders'),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'x-client-id': 'your x-client-id',
        'x-client-secret': 'your x-client-secret',
        'x-api-version': '2022-01-01',
        'x-request-id': 'developer_name',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(
        {
          "order_id": widget.cartId,
          "order_amount": widget.grandTotal,
          "order_currency": "INR",
          "order_note": "Additional order info",
          "customer_details": {
            "customer_id": widget.address.id,
            "customer_name": "name",
            "customer_email": widget.email,
            "customer_phone": widget.address.phone,
          }
        },
      ),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      if (jsonDecode(response.body)['status'] == 'OK') {
        debugPrint(jsonDecode(response.body)['order_id']);
        debugPrint('log');
        Logger.i(response.body);
        
        return jsonDecode(response.body)['order_id'];
      }
    }
    return '';
  }


  createSession() {
    createOrder().then((value) {
       try {
      var session = CFSessionBuilder()
          .setEnvironment(environment)
          .setOrderId(widget.cartId!)
          .setOrderToken(value)
          .build();
      return session;
    } on CFException catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.message);
    }

    });
   
    return null;
  }
```

But the response seems to null and payment gateway doesn't open. What might be going wrong with my code? I tried printing response but there in null value there,What might be going wrong? How do I get a response? I've done this in postman I get a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var decodedResponse = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)) as Map;
orderId = decodedResponse["order_id"] as String;
orderToken = decodedResponse["order_token"] as String;
```

Once the order is created and session is created, there are further steps, then only the checkout page will open. Refer this example - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cashfree_pg_sdk/example

Note :- Ideally, you shouldn't be creating order from app level. It should be done from your backend (Move the order creation to your backend).

Comment: I've tried this, same error how do I do it in backend?

Comment: How do I create order in backend?

Comment: The above post request which you are doing from flutter, move it to your backend. The flow should be like this, Flutter -> calls your backend (some end-point) -> Your backend calls Cashfree with the above request (create order) -> Cashfree sends response back to your backend -> Send order_token and order_id from your backend to flutter.

Answer (score 1):

replace header placeholders with actual values like your `x-client-secret` and others

Comment: In real code I have but I'm getting any response